# raspberry pi with udp?

Tags: video, rfid

I wanna use the Raspberry Pi to detect RFID to control the video of Unity.

My method is:

1. Raspberry Pi reads the value of UDP and sends a message back to the unity (Raspberry Pi and Unity use the same phone hotspot)
   [image]
2. After the value is got by Unity, Unity plays the video.
   then my first step, how to make the Raspberry Pi read the value?[image]

my question is:
1. I don't know where is the UDP port of the hotspot shared by mobile phone? I don't know which line is UDP port.
[image]
2.how to start first step？

[

Comment: If your raspberry-pi is connected to your phone hotspot with Wi-Fi (on your screenshot) , then here rapsberry-pi IP addr is `172.20.10.3` ... If your Unity is connected to the same network he must also have an IP addr : `172.20.10.X` where `X` is another number. Your Unity UDP server must be started on `172.20.10.X` (Unity) port `Y`. Your raspberry-pi must contact `172.20.10.X:PORT` as client for send requests and read response.

Comment: Please don't paste pictures of text. Instead paste the text output direct into the question.

Comment: firstly, I wanna say thx u so much also  new here without a programming foundation，plz bear with me.
This is my question:
I want to run this whole process. 
So I need to create three different independent programmings to run?（udp client 2，udp server 1）.  quote from https://pythontic.com/modules/socket/udp-client-server-example                                   
 
localIP     = "127.0.0.1"

localPort   = 20001

bufferSize  = 1024.

why this localPort just 20001
what is bufferSize  ？